# "Do Refactor" by keystroke, not clicking

Tags: phpstorm

Is it posssible to "Do Refactor" by keystroke, not clicking (while renaming multiple method occurances f.e.)?

(I need to write something more.)

Comment: Where? In Preview/Search list? Some screenshot for clarification will help a lot. If so -- `Alt+D` works fine for me (on Windows) if mnemonics are enabled, of course (by default, unless you have disabled them).

Comment: yes, Alt+D works! Make answer if You care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Alt + D</kbd> should do the job (if you have mnemonics enabled, of course, which is by default)

[image]